# if 4 numbers are entered do this, 3 do this, 2 do this and 1 do this jquery

Tags: jquery, split, calculator

I've got this little calculator I'm working on - http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/reCjA/31/

I'm currently wanting it so that you can enter CSS Margin shorthand into the margin form field and it returns the correct results.

ie.

```
if I enter 10, then I get a result of 10%
if I enter 10, 10 then I get a result of 10% 10%
if I enter 10, 10, 10 then I get a result of 10% 10% 10%
if I enter 10, 10, 10, 10 then I get a result of 10% 10% 10% 10%
```

at the moment if i enter 10, I get 10% 0 0 0

I want the 0 but only if all four numbers are there.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are entering those numbers in one text box, split them on comma and iterate through the array constructing the end result.

Comment: eh? This has been joined together from pieces I've found, played with and 'borrowed' I'm not sure how to do what you're thinking :/

Comment: It looks like your original fiddle works... ? http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/reCjA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's time for some conditional logic.

```
var value = getFromText();
var pieces = value.split(",")
                  .map(function (piece) { return piece.trim(); })
                  .filter(function (piece) { return !!piece; });

var derivedPieces = (function () {
    switch (pieces.length) {
        case 0:
            return [];
        case 1:
            return [pieces[0], pieces[0], pieces[0], pieces[0]];
        case 2:
            return [pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[0], pieces[1]];
        case 3:
            return [pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[1]];
        case 4:
            return pieces;
        default:
            return [pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3]];
    }
}());

var withPercentSigns = derivedPieces.map(function (piece) { return piece + "%"; })
                                    .join(" ");
```

[Working sample on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xauqb/)

Comment: this looks like what I need to do :o)

Comment: what bits do I need to change to get that to work in my fiddle? pieces = margins?

Answer (score 0):

Do your evaluations against the integer value, not the string.

```
if (shorthand1 != '0'){
    shorthand1 += '%';
}
```

becomes...

```
if (shorthand1 != 0){
        shorthand1 += '%';
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript these are equivalent, as long as you are using `!=` instead of `!==`.

Comment: Not according to the results of the fiddle. Make the change, the result changes.

Comment: Ah, I see why. It's because `"" != "0"` is `true` but `"" != 0` is `false`. Not really a solution that gets to the root of the problem... but I would be happy to remove my downvote if StackOverflow would let me >:(

Comment: Ok. I was trying to figure that out too. Thanks for looking into it. You're right, doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.length` property in your arrays (those that you get when you split a field) along with a `switch`.